# Won't add to database using script and php

Tags: php

I have some code in script that gets some values and posts them to php which (i already know works) should add to the database but doesnt? just wondering whats going wrong, my guess is that its never actually getting to my php file? any ideas?

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
{               
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        $.post("usersignup.php", { facebookid: response.id, email: response.email, firstname: response.first_name, lastname: response.last } );             
    });
```

appropriate part of usersignup.php looks like this

```
  mysql_select_db ($database);  
    $fbid = $_POST['facebookid'];
    $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
    $ln = $_POST['lastname'];
    $em = $_POST['email'];    
      $query = "INSERT INTO user";
      $query .= "(facebookid, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('$fbid','$fn','$ln','$em')";
      $results = mysql_query($query, $link);          
      $mediaid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Don't guess. Add error handling and some output that tracks your script's execution.

Comment: this is running on your website and not a fb non-iframe canvas, right?

Comment: yea on my website, user clicks login to facebook, they log in then $.post should be called

Comment: and you have included the jQuery libs correct?

Comment: no how do i do this? this could be the problem

Comment: you need to add the script tags to the head of your document either pointing to the js files on your server or on a CDN... just as you would do with any external javascript file. Maybe you should give this a read: [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there may be a php error lets add some error handling...

Modify your PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(!mysql_select_db ($database))
{
   echo 'Could not connect';
   exit;
}
else
{
  $fbid = $_POST['facebookid'];
  $fn = $_POST['firstname'];
  $ln = $_POST['lastname'];
  $em = $_POST['email'];    
  $query = "INSERT INTO user";
  $query .= "(facebookid, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('$fbid','$fn','$ln','$em')";

  if(!$results = mysql_query($query, $link))
  {
     echo 'Query failed: '.mysql_error();
     exit;
  }

  $mediaid = mysql_insert_id();
  echo 'Success: '. $mediaid;
}
```

And your js should alert the response:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
{               
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    $.post("usersignup.php", { 
        facebookid: response.id, 
        email: response.email, 
        firstname: response.first_name, 
        lastname: response.last 
      },
      function(rdata){ alert(rdata); }, 
      'text'
    );             
  });
});
```

Also keep an eye on your JS error console... if there is an issue with your JS its going to tell you.

---

[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is a shortcut for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) therefore it doesnt support the full config hash youre giving it. The signature is `$.post(url, data, successCallback)` if you need more control than this then use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: What should i use to run this, im doing this in dreamweaver and therefore getting no error message

Comment: Oh preview it in a browser - id recommend Firefox with [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) installed... never use the Dreamweaver preview... its useless ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got an SQL error.  Change your line to look like this:

```
$results = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

and see if an error is being generated.

I'm betting that one of your values is breaking the query.  You need to be running everything through mysql_real_escape_string(), at a minimum.

```
$fn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
```

Comment: No neither fix it. i think it maybe that its not completing $.post but i dont know why, does $.post have to be called?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file does not create a connection to the MySQL server, and `$database` is not defined.

Comment: it is defined, and created just not in the code i have pasted

Comment: @James: Right, so when you said "usersignup.php looks like this", you were lying. Please amend your question accordingly.